fastify/sessions cant implement my own session store using Prisma
I use typescript. I want to implement a session based authentication system. So, Ive decided to use fastify/session. And Prisma for storing the sessions. My problem is when I request to "/" path (which you can see the below) it doesnt return anything. My postman shows only "Sending request..." and nothing is returning. But database creates the session. And in console I can see the sessionId (which i printed in console.) and its matches with the sessionId in database. What can I do to solve this?
My index.ts file which I implement the fastify and sessionStore:
import Fastify, { FastifyReply, FastifyRequest } from "fastify";
import fastifyCookie from "@fastify/cookie";
import fastifySession from "@fastify/session";
import { db } from "./libs/db";

const fastify = Fastify();

const PORT = Number(process.env.PORT) || 3000;

fastify.register(fastifyCookie);
fastify.register(fastifySession, {
  store: {
    set: async (sid: string, session: object) => {
      await db.session.upsert({
        where: { sid },
        update: { session: JSON.stringify(session) },
        create: { sid, session: JSON.stringify(session) },
      });
    },
    get: async (sid: string) => {
      try {
        const storedSession = await db.session.findUnique({ where: { sid } });
        return storedSession ? JSON.parse(storedSession.session) : null;
      } catch (error) {
        return null;
      }
    },
    destroy: async (sid: string) => {
      await db.session.delete({ where: { sid } });
    },
  },
  cookieName: "sid",
  secret: "supersecretkeysupersecretkeysupersecretkeysupersecretkey",
  cookie: {
    maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60,
    secure: process.env.NODE_ENV === "production",
  },
});

fastify.get("/", (req: FastifyRequest, res: FastifyReply) => { 
  console.log(req.session.sessionId);
  return { success: "Test sucess!" };
});

try {
  fastify.listen({ port: PORT });
  console.log(`Server is listening port ${PORT}`);
} catch (error) {
  fastify.log.error(error);
  process.exit(1);
}


My schema.prisma file:
generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
}

datasource db {
  provider = "mysql"
  url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
}


model Session {
  sid     String   @id @default(uuid()) 
  session String  
}

And what caught my eye is that in index.d.ts file which source code of the fastify/session the declaration of get, set and destory method are like this:
set(
  sessionId: string,
  session: Fastify.Session,
  callback: Callback
): void;
get(
  sessionId: string,
  callback: CallbackSession
): void;
destroy(sessionId: string, callback: Callback): void;

All of them return void, is it the case? But if get method returns anything how can i indicate that what is the session which i got brought from the database or something? Or my Session schema in prisma.schema file, is it the case?

Simply returning is not enough: you should be calling reply.send():
fastify.get("/", (req: FastifyRequest, res: FastifyReply) => { 
  console.log(req.session.sessionId);

  res.send({ success: "Test success!" });
});


Source: documentation.
If you read the documentation, there are also several options such as using async/await syntax.

I got it. But thanks. Its not about res.send() its about callback function in store functions. (set, get, destroy.) I implement it and its solved. Thanks.
